# How can I fix python printing unnecessary "in range" information

Tags: python, random

I want to make a advanced password generator. And I want to add a feature where each password is saved in a text file. But at the last part where it generates another password, Python prints each character step by step this causes to save each character! My computer crashed 3 times today because of this bug. Sorry for all the bad grammar or bad explanation.

Anyways here is my code:

```
import random

Alphabet = "abcdefghilmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHILMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789()]\%$*@!><?"
FileAlphabet = "abcdefghilmnopqrstuvwxyz"
number = input("Number of passwords? ")
number = int(number)

length = input("Password length? ")
length = int(length)



for p in range(number):
    password = ''
    for c in range(length):
        password += random.choice(Alphabet)


print(password)


text = password

saveFile = open("MOST_RECENT_PASSWORD.txt", 'w')
saveFile.write(text)
saveFile.close()

new = input("Generate another password? yes/no" )
FileName = ''

if new == "yes":
    for pwd in range(number):
        password = ''
        for c in range(length):
            password += random.choice(Alphabet)
            FileName += random.choice(FileAlphabet)
            password += random.choice(Alphabet)
            print(password)
            saveFile = open(FileName + ".txt", 'w')
            saveFile.write(text)
            saveFile.close()
```

Comment: saveFile etc is under the ‘for pwd in range...’ - move it leftward one level out of the for loop.

Comment: Ok it did solve the "saving every step" bug but it can't save every password the user wants

Comment: Ok, glad it helped, so update the post with what it’s now doing.

Comment: No need i fixed the bug by removing 4 lines of code

Comment: ... which were?

Comment: There was some code where you could select the number of passwords and the length I don't really need them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last 2 for loops.
especially the

```
for c in range(length):
            password += random.choice(Alphabet)
            FileName += random.choice(FileAlphabet)
            password += random.choice(Alphabet)
            print(password)
            saveFile = open(FileName + ".txt", 'w')
            saveFile.write(text)
            saveFile.close()
```

you're saying that for every character of your password it should:

increment the password by some random letter

**And change the filename to a random letter**

then increment the password again with some random letter

//printing the password is kinda ok allthough it only prints 2 characters

**and then you save the 2 characters in ONE file**

and redo every time

The bold parts are where the problems lie.
You have to move `FileName += random.choice(FileAlphabet)`
to the left, so under `for c in range(length):`
then also move

```
saveFile = open(FileName + ".txt", 'w')
saveFile.write(text)
saveFile.close()
```

to the left so it doesn't loop it.

**For you the solution should be**

```
for pwd in range(number):
        password = ''
        for c in range(length):
            password += random.choice(Alphabet)
            password += random.choice(Alphabet)
            print(password)
        FileName += random.choice(FileAlphabet)
        saveFile = open(FileName + ".txt", 'w')
        saveFile.write(text)
        saveFile.close(
```

)